# How to get elements inside a selected row in a NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

I have an `NSTableView` of content type `View Based` with two columns.

My objects are structured as follows:

```
Table View
    Table Column
        Table Cell View
            Text Field
    Table Column
        Table Cell View
            Popup Button
```

For a selected row, I want to get an element inside the selected row for a specific column. Specifically, I want to get the `Text Field` in the first column for the selected row.

I have an outlet to the table view and I have the index of the selected row so far, but that's about it:

```
- (void)getSelectedTextField
{
    NSInteger selected = [tableView selectedRow];
}
```

Any ideas on how I can go about tackling this problem?

**Edit**: This is what I am trying to do: I want to change the text field to be in an editing state and focus on it so the user can start editing the text field value as soon as it is selected

Comment: What is it that you need to access the elements for? If you just need to get the data you should be storing it in a NSTableViewDataSource and then providing that datasource to the NSTableView.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa: It is to modify one of the controls. Specifically, I want to change the text field to be in an editing state and focus on it so the user can start editing the text field value as soon as it is selected.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I seemed to have solved my own problem:

```
- (void)getSelectedTextField
{
    NSInteger selected = [tableView selectedRow];

    // Get row at specified index
    NSTableCellView *selectedRow = [tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:selected makeIfNecessary:YES];

    // Get row's text field
    NSTextField *selectedRowTextField = [selectedRow textField];

    // Focus on text field to make it auto-editable
    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:selectedRowTextField];

    // Set the keyboard carat to the beginning of the text field
    [[selectedRowTextField currentEditor] setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
}
```

Comment: Sir, can u please help me to get a selected item of a combobox, which i added in one of the column insted of textfield. Any help is great

Answer (score 6):

Use can get all element of table view cell by get its subview. Suggest show log list subview before use it

```
NSInteger index = [self.tableViewFiles selectedRow];

// Get row at specified index of column 0 ( We just have 1 column)
NSTableCellView *cellView = [self.tableViewFiles viewAtColumn:0 row:index makeIfNecessary:YES];

// Get row's checkBox ( at index 0, textFields is 1,2)
NSButton *checkBox = [[cellView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text field is the only subview of your table view cell, you can get a reference to it with the following code, and select its text, so it's ready for editing:

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
   NSInteger row = [notification.object selectedRow];
   NSTextField *tf = [[[notification.object viewAtColumn:0 row:row makeIfNecessary:NO]subviews] lastObject];
   [tf selectText:tf.stringValue];
}
```